# TypeErr: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to create a button system where if you do not have a specific role, you are unable to use a button. However, the code I have created doesn't seem to work.

```
collector.on('collect', async interaction => {
        const wikiStaffRole = interaction.user.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Staff");

        if (interaction.customId === "yes") {
          if (!wikiStaffRole) {
            return interaction.followUp({ content: `${interaction.user} dude you need to be a staff member`, ephmeral: true });
          }
          newUserEmbed.edit({ embeds: [], content: 'This report has been marked as completed.', components: [] });
          return;
         } else if (interaction.customId === "no") {
          if (!wikiStaffRole) {
            return interaction.followUp({ content: `${interaction.user} dude you need to be a staff member`, ephmeral: true });
          }
          newUserEmbed.edit({ embeds: [], content: 'This report has been denied.', components: [] });
          return;
        } else if (interaction.customId === "what") {
          if (!wikiStaffRole) {
            return interaction.followUp({ content: `${interaction.user} dude you need to be a staff member`, ephmeral: true });
          }
          newUserEmbed.edit({ embeds: [], content: 'This report has been marked as inconclusive.', components: [] });
          return;
        }
        });
```

Instead, I just get an error that states that it cannot read the property 'roles' of undefined. I cannot figure out any ways to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried accessing the non-existent `guild` property of a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object. This property does not exist on `User`s but does exist on [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=guild) and [`Interaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=guild) objects. This code should work:

```js
const wikiStaffRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Staff")
```

Keep in mind that if it is not in a guild, this will throw an error. You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) to prevent that

```js
const wikiStaffRole = interaction.guild?.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Staff")
```

I think you wanted to check if the member had the role though. You are actually checking if the *entire server* has the role. This will check only the member's roles

```js
const wikiStaffRole = interaction.member?.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Staff")
//optional chaining because member would be null if it was sent in a DM
```